# NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy for an Integral function with several singular points

Tags: numerical-integration

The integral function is given as

```
f[x_] := (110 (1 + x^3) (13 - 1139 x^4 + 26 x^6))/( 3 x (1 - 113 x^4 + 2 x^6) (1 - 58 x^4 + 2 x^6))
```

with five singular points when x>=0

```
x0 /. NSolve[x0 (1 - 113 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) (1 - 58 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) == 0 && x0 >= 0, x0]
```

out[]={0, 0.30684, 0.362775, 5.38511, 7.51664}

when the numerical integration is calculated from 0.2 to 6

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0.2, 6},Exclusions -> (x0 /. 
NSolve[x0 (1 - 113 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) (1 - 58 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) == 0 && 
  x0 >= 0, x0]), Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

(*213.109*)
```

the value 213.109 is given.
However, when the numerical integration is calculated from 0 to 6, a warning is shown

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0., 6}, Exclusions -> (x0 /.NSolve[x0 (1 - 113 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) (1 - 58 x0^4 + 2 x0^6) == 0 && 
  x0 >= 0, x0]), Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {4.77568*10^-30}. NIntegrate obtained 361150. and 141538. for the integral and error estimates.

Q1: How could i obtain the right numerical for the integration range from 0 to 6?

Q2: Is there a analytical solution for the integration?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have to exclude the singularities of f[x]!

Comment: Yeah, the singularities should be excluded. But some other problems still exist, and it is presented in the re-edit question.

Comment: You can't use the principal value method on $[a,b]$ when there is an asymptote (pole) at $a$.  Such is the case when the integration range starts at $0$ for your integrand.

Comment: By the way, your integral can be evaluated symbolically (exactly) using `Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}, PrincipalValue -> True]` for whatever numbers `a` and `b` you wish to choose.  If `a = 0`, then `Integrate` will tell you that the integral does not converge.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your comments. Follow your idea,  'Integrate[f[x],{x,0.2,4},PrincipalValue->True]' gives the result with an imaginary number and the warning message _{*Integrate::idiv: Integral of ((1+x^3) (13-1139 x^4+26 x^6))/(x (1-113 x^4+2 x^6) (1-58 x^4+2 x^6)) does not converge on {0.2,4}.* }_

Comment: Yeah, it seems the function is too hard for `Integrate` to analyze accurately. There are computational limits, and I suppose this is one.  It might be worth reporting it to WRI in case it's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand is a rational function, so there is definitely a symbolic solution.  It seems that `Integrate[f[x], {x, 1/5, 4}]` is a bit too hard for `Integrate` to figure out.  But if we use partial fractions and integrate the parts separately, we can get the answer.

```
roots = x /. Solve[3 x (1 - 113 x^4 + 2 x^6) (1 - 58 x^4 + 2 x^6) == 0, x]

coeffs = Solve[
   Table[(110 (1 + x^3) (13 - 1139 x^4 + 26 x^6))/12 == 
       Numerator@ Together@Sum[A[k]/(x - roots[[k]]), {k, Length@roots}] /. 
      x -> roots[[j]],
    {j, Length@roots}],
   Table[A[k], {k, Length@roots}]
   ];

int = Sum[
  Integrate[A[k]/(x - roots[[k]]) /. First@coeffs, {x, 1/5, 4}, 
   PrincipalValue -> True],
  {k, Length@roots}]

N[int, 16]

(*  214.1951292990900 + 0.*10^-14 I  *)
```

Compare with `NIntegrate[]`:

```
NIntegrate[
 (110*(1 + x^3)*(13 - 1139*x^4 + 26*x^6))/
  (3*x*(1 - 113*x^4 + 2*x^6)*(1 - 58*x^4 + 2*x^6)),
 {x, 1/5, 
  Root[1 - 113*#1^4 + 2*#1^6 & , 3, 0], 
  Root[1 - 58*#1^4 + 2*#1^6 & , 3, 0], 4}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

(*  214.195  *)
```

Comment: Grateful for your answer! You point out  that  "there is definitely a symbolic solution when the integrand is a rational funtion", would you mind to recommd some books or other materials for me to learn more about it?

Comment: @keanhy14 It's in most every calculus textbook and follows from the method of partial fractions and the facts that $A/(Bx+C)^k$ and $(Ax + B)/(Cx^2+Dx+E)^k$ can be integrated in terms of $\ln$ and $\arctan$. Over the complex numbers, polynomials can be factored completely into linear factors, so you only need that t $A/(Bx+C)^k$ can be integrated in terms of logarithms. The denominator of your example has distinct linear factors so I used the "shortcut" method for the PF decomposition. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions

Comment: That's exactly what i need, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have one singular point between 4 and 6.  First I find it, then identify it in NIntegrate as {4,singularPoint,6}, and then specify Method->"PrincipalValue":

```
f[x_] := (110 (x^3 + 1) (26 x^6 - 1139 x^4 + 13))/(
  3 x (2 x^6 - 113 x^4 + 1) (2 x^6 - 58 x^4 + 1));
Plot[f[x], {x, 4, 6}]
myRoots = x /. Solve[Denominator[f[x]] == 0, x];
myRoots[[7]] // N
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 4, myRoots[[7]], 6}, Method -> 
 "PrincipalValue"]

-1.08626 + 1.72876*10^-15 I
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion of the strategy of "PrincipalValue", and it really works for [4, 6]. However, where the integration range is [0,6]. The warning is shown at x=0, see the re-edit question.

Comment: The function behaviour `f[x]~1/x`near x=0 shows that the  integration cannot converge!

Answer (score 1):

evaluate the singularities (roots of the denominator)

```
xEX = x /. NSolve[Denominator[f[x]] == 0, x, Reals]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, GridLines -> {xEX, None}]
```

[image]

integration

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 4, 6}, Exclusions -> xEX,Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
(*-1.08626*)
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion!  The strategy of "PrincipalValue"  really works for [4, 6]. However, when the integration range is [0,6]. The warning is shown at x=0, see the re-edit question.